# Using pytest parametrize with DRF test

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-testing, pytest-django

Now I have code like this:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class MyTestClass(ApiTestCase):
    fixtures = ['some_fixtures.json', ]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('field, reverse_ordering', [
        ('id', False),
        ('id', True)])
    def test_ordering(self, field, reverse_ordering):
        # some test function
```

Every time it is failed with that error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_ordering (my_module.tests.MyTestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: test_ordering() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'field' and 'reverse_ordering'
```

How it is possible to use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator with tests inside of `APITestCase` from DRF tests class?
Maybe there is some another way to parametrize tests (but not loops)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Maybe there is some another way to parametrize tests (but not loops)?

Since Python 3.4, parametrizing is available in the standard library using [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests):

```
class MyTest(APITestCase):

    test_ordering_params = [('id', False), ('id', True)]

    def test_ordering(self):
        for field, reverse_ordering in self.test_ordering_params:
            with self.subTest(field=field, reverse=reverse_ordering):
                query = ('-' if reverse_ordering else '') + field
                resp = self.client.get(reverse('url-name'), {'ordering': query}, format='json')
                assert resp.data
```

However, if you want to gain real benefits from using `pytest`, consider moving away from `unittest`-style class tests to test functions. The same test using `pytest` combined with `pytest-django` plugin:

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

@pytest.fixture
def apiclient():
    return APIClient()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('field, reverse_ordering', [('id', False), ('id', True)])
def test_ordering(apiclient, db, field, reverse_ordering):
    query = ('-' if reverse_ordering else '') + field
    resp = apiclient.get(reverse('url-name'), {'ordering': query}, format='json')
    assert resp.data
```

#### Edit

You may also take a look at the [`parameterized`](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/) library, which offers `pytest`-like parametrization for test class methods. Example:

```
from parameterized import parameterized


class MyTest(APITestCase):

    @parameterized.expand([('id', False), ('id', True)])
    def test_ordering(self, field, reverse_ordering):
        query = ('-' if reverse_ordering else '') + field
        resp = self.client.get(reverse('url-name'), {'ordering': query}, format='json')
        assert resp.data
```

Comment: I am using `subTest` now, but i do not like the way it looks. All my test classes are inherited from my own specific `BaseTestClass(ApiTestCase)`. (I mean I can not rewrite it for separated test functions)

Comment: From my experience, any functionality residing in a base test class can be always refactored to a fixture, resulting in less boilerplate code in the end. But of course, if you already have hundreds of `unittest`-style tests, refactoring all of them is a monstruous task to be done at once.

Comment: You may also take a look at the `parameterized` library, which offers pytest-like parametrization for test class methods. I have updated the answer with a usage example.

Comment: Thank you, i'll use it!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6):

`ApiTestCase` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` which would not support parametrization as mentioned in [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses):

> The following pytest features work in unittest.TestCase subclasses:
>
> - Marks: skip, skipif, xfail;
> - Auto-use fixtures;
>
> The following pytest
>   features do not work, and probably never will due to different design
>   philosophies:
>
> - Fixtures (except for autouse fixtures, see below);
> - Parametrization;
> - Custom hooks;
>
> Third party plugins may or may not work well, depending
>   on the plugin and the test suite.

Comment: I've updated question here (last line). It is ok, I can not use it. But what I can use like parametrize?